# IIS8 Unable to upload files above 2mb

Tags: file-upload, iis-8

I've been trying to upload files larger then 2 mb to a website running on a Windows 2012 server with IIS 8. I can upload files under 2 mb so its not a timeout problem, anything above it causes it to refuse the file (any extension).

What i have done so far is changing the defaults to:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="153600" executionTimeout="900" />

<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" /> 
</requestFiltering>

ASP Max request Entity Body Limit to 20000000
```

From what i've read, maxRequestLength is in KB, maxAllowedContentLength is in Bytes and should be larger then maxRequestLength and ASP Max request Entity Body Limit is also in bytes.

Sadly the changes did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify the maxAllowedContentLength setting in the web.config?

You can increase the maximum file size by modify the maxAllowedContentLength setting in the web.config file like the example below:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Now you can upload files that are 2 GB in size.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I did change that setting (see submitted code block). No luck there :(.